# Allowing user to import any file in OpenLayers 3 map control?

Tags: shapefile, openlayers

I have started exploring the OpenLayers 3 library.

I have seen the examples but i am not able to find the way for import shapefile and load it on OpenLayers's map control.

I want give option for importing shapefile and render on the map control. something similar to browse the shapefile from client side and load it.

Answer (score 7):

check this [demo](http://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/). It seems to be what you look for.

If you like it download it form [here](https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js)

Have also a look at this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138155/allow-client-to-upload-layers-to-openlayers-3)

Comment: I have tired it but its not fulfilling my requirements. i want to load the shape file without converting it to GeoJson format.

Comment: So what do you want to do with the shapefile????? Just load it. Dont you want to plot it on your map?????

Comment: yes i just want to load my shape file and then based on the live data i want  to create the new shape file layer.

Comment: There is no such "shape file layer" in ol3. Either you convert it in geojson,gml, kml ....etc and plot it on your map(no action on server, just on client). Or you upload it on the server --> create a layer in geoserver ---> plot it as wms/wfs layer (too much processing on server)

Comment: Can you help me on this "http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177226/web-application-using-dot-spatial-not-rendering-shapefile"